# Changing a Second Value withing a Vector Object in C++

Tags: c++, class, pointers, object, vector

I'm quite new at C++, and am learning about vectors and all that fun stuff. I'm trying to figure out how I can have the user add a room on his selected floor. I have most of the problem done, but just that part I am having a hard time figuring out, any help would be appreciated! The main issue I think is at the function ReplaceFloor, but I have no idea how to make it in a way that the user selects Choice 4, then enters the floor that he wants a room to be added, and have that floor vector store one more room in it. Thank you for your help in advance! I tried to make it as best understandable as I could- sorry I'm quite new.

```
// Main.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Floor.h" // must include Floor header file
#include "Room.h" // must include Room header file
#include "AccessPoint.h" // must include AccessPoint header file
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

// functions that fills up all Floors
void fillFloor(vector<Floor>&);
void deletesFloor(vector<Floor>&);
void replaceFloor(vector<Floor>&);
// functions that fills up all Rooms
void fillRoom(vector<Room>&);
void deletesRoom(vector<Room>&);
// functions that fills up all Access Points
void fillAccessPoint(vector<AccessPoint>&);

void printFloorVector(const vector<Floor>&); // prints the information of all floors
void printRoomVector(const vector<Room>&); // prints the information of all Rooms
void printAccessPointVector(const vector<AccessPoint>&); // prints the information of all Access Points

// Variable Declaration
int roomNumber;
int accessPointNumber;
int floorID =0;
int roomID = 0;
int accessPointID =0;
int floorTotal;

// Check Floor Number To Add Room To
int floorForRoomAdd =0;

int main() {
    // Declaring Variables
    int exitCheck = 0;   // Used to loop if the user wants to check for more than date range
    int choice;

    // Creating Vector for Class Floor
    vector<Floor> Building;
    vector<Room> Floor;
    vector<AccessPoint> Room;

    // Calling the functions
    cout << "How Many Floors Does This Building Contain? ";

    cin >> floorTotal;
    cout << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < floorTotal; i++) { // Gathers total floors number + How many rooms for each floor
    fillFloor(Building);
        cout << "How Many Rooms Are On This Floor? : " ;
        cin >> roomNumber;
        cout << endl;

        for (int b = 0; b < roomNumber; b++) { // Gathers total Room number + How many access points for each room
        fillRoom(Floor);    
            cout << "How Many Access Points Are In This Room? : ";  
            cin >> accessPointNumber;
            cout << endl;

            for (int c = 0; c < accessPointNumber; c++) { // Gather total access points + Status of each access point
            fillAccessPoint(Room);
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "##############################################################" << endl;
    cout << "#                       Done Building                        #" << endl;   
    cout << "##############################################################" << endl << endl;


    while (exitCheck <1) {

        // TITLE
        cout<<"\nNETWORK MONITORING ACCESS POINTS \n";
        cout<<"----------------------------------"; 
        cout<<"\n1 - Display Building Information"; // Check (Some minor issue)
        cout<<"\n2 - Add a Floor"; // Check
        cout<<"\n3 - Delete a Floor"; // Check
        cout<<"\n4 - Add a Room"; 
        cout<<"\n5 - Delete a Room"; 
        cout<<"\n6 - Add a Network Access Point";
        cout<<"\n7 - Delete a Network Access Point";
        cout<<"\n8 - Toggle Access Point Status";
        cout<<"\n9 - Change Access Point Date";
        cout<<"\n0 - Exit"; // Check 
        cout<<"\n";

        // Input 
        cout<<"\nChoice: ";
        cin>> choice;

        // Determine Choice
        if (choice == 1) {
        cout << "##############################################################" << endl;
        cout << "#                 The status of the building is              #" << endl;
        cout << "##############################################################" << endl << endl;
        printFloorVector(Building); // Prints end result
        cout << endl;
        printRoomVector(Floor); // Prints end result
        cout << endl;
        printAccessPointVector(Room); // Prints end result
        cout << endl;
        }
        else if (choice == 2) { // Adds a floor

            fillFloor(Building);
            cout << "Floor Has Been Created!" ;
            //cin >> roomNumber;
            //cout << endl;

        }
        else if (choice == 3) { // Deletes a floor
            deletesFloor(Building);
        }
        else if (choice == 4) { // Adds a room
            cout << "What Floor Would You Like To Add A Room To?";
            cin >> floorForRoomAdd; 
            cout << endl;
            replaceFloor(Building); //code where floor has the room info
            cout << "How Many Rooms Are On This Floor? : " ;
            cin >> roomNumber;  
            cout << endl;
        }
        else if (choice == 5) { // Deletes a room
            cout << "What Floor Is The Room That You Would Like To Have Deleted?";
            //code where floor has the room info
            deletesRoom(Floor);
        }
        else if (choice == 6) { // Adds an access point
            cout << "How Many Access Points Are In This Room? : ";  
            cin >> accessPointNumber;
            cout << endl;
        }
        else if (choice == 7) { // Deletes an access point

        }
        else if (choice == 8) { // Changes access point status

        }
        else if (choice == 9) { // Change access point date

        }
        else if (choice == 0) { // Exits
            exitCheck = 2;
        }
        else {
            cout<< "Input Not Valid. Please Provide A Valid Input";
        }
}
    // Display the Purpose and that Program has now ended
    cout << "\nThe Purpose Of This Program Is To Create A Building Network " << endl;
    cout << "Access Operation That Uses Vectors, Clas Callings, And Loops" << endl;
    cout << "\nThe Program Has Now Ended\n" << endl;
    return 0; 
}// End Program

void fillFloor(vector<Floor>& newBuilding) {
        floorID++;
        cout << "----------------------"<< endl;
        cout << "Floor Numer: "<< floorID << endl;
        cout << "----------------------"<< endl;

        Floor newFloor (floorID, roomNumber); // This istantiated the object in vector, will be passing floorID and roomNumber to the new object
        newBuilding.push_back(newFloor); // adds a new object to the newBuilding vector
        cout << endl;

}

// Deletes Floor
void deletesFloor(vector<Floor>& newBuilding) {
        int deletedFloor;   
        cout << "Enter Floor Number To Delete It"<< endl;
        cin >> deletedFloor;
        cout << "Floor Numer: "<< deletedFloor << " Has Been Deleted!" << endl;
        deletedFloor = deletedFloor - 1;
        newBuilding.erase(newBuilding.begin()+deletedFloor);

}

// Replace Floor Info
void replaceFloor(vector<Floor>& newBuilding) {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < newBuilding.size(); i++) {
            if (newBuilding[i].getFloorID() == floorForRoomAdd) {
                int changeRoomTotal = newBuilding[i].getRoomNumber;
                newBuilding[i].getRoomNumber = changeRoomTotal + 1;
            }
        }

}
// Insert New Room
void insertRoom(vector<Room>& newFloor) {
            roomID++;
            cout << "What Floor Will This Room Be Added In?"<< endl;
            cout << "Room Numer: "<< roomID << endl;
            cout << "----------------------"<< endl;

            Room newRoom (roomID, accessPointNumber); // This istantiated the object in vector, will be passing floorID and roomNumber to the new object
            newFloor.insert(newFloor.begin()+3, newRoom);
            cout << endl;
}

void fillRoom(vector<Room>& newFloor) {
            roomID++;
            cout << "----------------------"<< endl;
            cout << "Room Numer: "<< roomID << endl;
            cout << "----------------------"<< endl;

            Room newRoom (roomID, accessPointNumber); // This istantiated the object in vector, will be passing floorID and roomNumber to the new object
            newFloor.push_back(newRoom); // adds a new object to the newFloor vector
            cout << endl;
}
// Deletes Room
void deletesRoom(vector<Room>& newFloor) {
        int deletedRoom;    
        cout << "Enter Room Number To Delete It"<< endl;
        cin >> deletedRoom;
        cout << "Room Number: "<< deletedRoom << " Has Been Deleted!" << endl;
        deletedRoom = deletedRoom - 1;
        newFloor.erase(newFloor.begin()+deletedRoom);

}

void fillAccessPoint(vector<AccessPoint>& newRoom) {
    bool accessPointStatus;

                accessPointID++;
                cout << "----------------------"<< endl;
                cout << "Access Point Number: "<< accessPointID << endl;
                cout << "----------------------"<< endl;
                cout << "What Is The Status Of This Access Point : ";   
                cin >> accessPointStatus;

                AccessPoint newAccessPoint (accessPointID, accessPointStatus); // This istantiated the object in vector, will be passing floorID and roomNumber to the new object
                newRoom.push_back(newAccessPoint); // adds a new object to the newFloor vector
                cout << endl;       
}

// This will display all of the building information
void printFloorVector(const vector<Floor>& newBuilding) {

    cout << "The Building Has: " << floorTotal << " Floors" << endl;
    unsigned int newBuildingSize = newBuilding.size();

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < newBuildingSize; i++) {
        cout << "Floor ID: " << newBuilding[i].getFloorID() << endl;
        cout << "Total Rooms: " << newBuilding[i].getRoomNumber() << endl;
    }   
}

void printRoomVector(const vector<Room>& newFloor) {    
    unsigned int newFloorSize = newFloor.size();

    for(unsigned int a = 0; a < newFloorSize; a++) {
            cout << "Room ID: " << newFloor[a].getRoomID() << endl;
            cout << "Total Access Points: " << newFloor[a].getAccessPointNumber() << endl;          
    }
}

void printAccessPointVector(const vector<AccessPoint>& newRoom) {
    unsigned int newRoomSize = newRoom.size();

    for(unsigned int b = 0; b < newRoomSize; b++) {
        cout << "Access Point Number: " << newRoom[b].getAccessPointID() << endl;
        cout << "Access Point Status: " << newRoom[b].getAccessPointStatus() << endl;   
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: In this line why you are getting input as 'cin >> roomNumber;'. I think instead of this you need to print your room number.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you want to fix the replaceFloor function so that you can add one more room to a particular floor.

In the code, you correctly identify the position of the floor element inside the building vector using the line: `if (newBuilding[i].getFloorID() == floorForRoomAdd)`

In addition to the steps you have done, you also need to actually add the room to the floor vector. For that, you can access the floor vector as `newBuilding[i]` and then call `newBuilding[i].push_back(newRoomObject)` where newRoomObject contains all the information you have specified for the new floor to be added. This will result in the room to be added in the floor vector.

If I have misunderstood your query in any manner, please mention that so I may update my answer. One query which I have, but can't comment due to lack of reputation is, why have you used `newFloor.insert(newFloor.begin()+3, newRoom);` in the insert room function. The only reason for the +3 constant I can see is that you may be thinking that you are saying that the first two spots are taken up by floorID and room no. Even in that case, it should be +2. Also, even then, floorID and room no will most probably be two integers (or some number), whereas the rooms are objects. You cannot mix those types in an array. Please clarify.

Comment: Sir, your understanding is correct; what would be the better form, and how would I add the room to the floor vector?

Thank you very much!

Comment: @Temanibble : To add a room, you would first have to define a room object which you will push back in the corresponding floor vector. To define the room object, you first need the details for the access points. So also ask the user for the access point details for the room, or assume some default values. After this object has been created, just add it to the floor vector after correcting the floor parameters such as number of rooms.

Also, what do you mean by the better form?

Comment: Would it be possible if you could include a code how to? I really apologize, I've been trying to figure out this for roughly 10 hrs today and my mind is just overloaded trying to understand.

I really appreciate you helping me out.
Thank you

Comment: I'm unable to do so, because I have a really busy week up ahead of me. I can do so after 22nd December, but by then it would be too late for you I guess. Just try to implement what I wrote. Go over it step by step. Take a break, and get back to it. Don't worry, I'm sure you can do it.